# Can't insert record.the given error "Table "tbCustomer" does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2

I do not have identity column on table.I dont need identity for the coulmn named as CountryID. I pass CountryID value from client request for the CountryId column as primary key. once I executed stored procedure I am given the mentioned error as "Table   does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation". How can I insert record without getting this error ?

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
```

[image]

```
   var result =  await tDBContext.Query<SpResponseMessage>().FromSql("exec sp_synchCountry " +
                 "@p0, @p1, @p2",
                  objCountry.CountryID,
                  objCountry.CountryName
                  objCountry.LanguageId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I insert record ?

Comment: Do you have identity in CountryID? Can you pass the 'code line' for that column

Beware, if you have, identity is using like 'IDENTITY(1, 2)', means start from 1 and increase for 2

Comment: No. I dont have identity column.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbCountry]( [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL, [CountryName] [nvarchar](200) NULL, [LanguageId] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_tbCountry1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CountryId] ASC, [LanguageId] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: the only possible way sucessing for this is add seperate column Id as identity column..where are the sql developers who has strong knowlege of this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure multiple properties to be the key of an entity (known as a composite key). Composite keys can only be configured using the Fluent API - conventions will never setup a composite key and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one.

```
 public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Country> tbCountry { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.CountryID, c.LanguageId });
    }
}
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#fluent-api